# Winforms FlowLayoutPanel remove unneeded spaces with autosize controls

Tags: c#, winforms, flowlayoutpanel

I have **FlowLayoutPanel** with

**AutoScroll = True**

**FlowDirection = LeftToRight**

**WrapContents = True**

Added controls dynamically have **same Width** but **AutoSize** in **Height**. So the panel will be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k30Yh.jpg), which has vertical spaces between items. As the height of row managed by the greatest height of controls. So I want to remove these unneeded spaces, and the final result will be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUpqm.jpg).

If there's no way to do it with FlowLayoutPanel, What's the proper idea to done it perfectly ?

Comment: Use 3 (or many) FlowLayoutPanel.

Comment: You can create your own panel and do the positioning in custom code. Or you can do as @AlexanderPetrov suggested and create FlowLayoutpanels als Columns with FlowDirection = TopDown.

Comment: These good ideas, but I try to find more powerful solution, Thanks.

Comment: It is one of the standard software engineering problems, the *bin packing problem*.  Even the 1-dimensional case is NP-awful.  Solve it in O(n) time and you'll never have to work again for the rest of your life.  Good luck with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Its a matrix and should be treated like a matrix.
2. my opinion is that `Panel` is more appropriate than a `FlowLayoutpanel` here.
3. please see my suggestion and output to achieve such a behavior.

**clarification:** this code needs improvements to be adapted to all possible cases but you can learn from it the basic idea how to deal with such problem.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Example();
    }

    // space beetween controls (top and right)
    public int MarginSpace = 8;
    // first element location
    public Point StartPoint = new Point(10, 10);
    private void Example()
    {
        var fixesWidth = 70;
        List<Label> randomLables = new List<Label>();
        Random rand = new Random();
        // generate lables with random heights
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Label lr = new Label();
            var randheight = rand.Next(60, 120);
            lr.Size = new Size(fixesWidth, randheight);
            lr.Text = i.ToString();
            lr.BackColor = Color.Black;
            lr.ForeColor = Color.White;
            randomLables.Add(lr);
        }

        // check how many elements in one "column" (possible also to add right+left margin)
        var cols = panel1.Width / fixesWidth;
        // create matrix object to get locations of each label
        MyMatrix m = new MyMatrix(cols, randomLables.Count, 15, 70, StartPoint);
        m.SetMatrix(randomLables);
        int counter = 0;
        // pupulate all lables with the points from MyMatrix object
        foreach (Point p in m.pointsMatrix)
        {
            randomLables[counter].Location = p;
            panel1.Controls.Add(randomLables[counter]);
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
class MyMatrix
{
    private int Rows;
    private int TotalElements;
    private int Cols;
    private int Margin;
    private int ElementWidth;
    private Point StartPoint;
    public MyMatrix(int cols, int totalelements, int margin, int elementwidth, Point startingpoint)
    {
        this.Cols = cols;
        this.TotalElements = totalelements;
        this.Margin = margin;
        this.ElementWidth = elementwidth;
        this.StartPoint = startingpoint;

        // calculate number of rows
        Rows = totalelements / cols;
    }

    public List<Point> pointsMatrix = new List<Point>();
    int cellCounter = 0;
    public void SetMatrix(List<Label> Labels)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Cols; j++)
            {

                var x = StartPoint.X + j * (Margin + ElementWidth);
                var y = StartPoint.Y;
                if (cellCounter >= Cols)
                {
                    // find the parallel cell in the row above
                    y = pointsMatrix[cellCounter - Cols].Y + Labels[cellCounter - Cols].Height + Margin;
                }
                else
                {
                    // do nothing it is first row
                }

                Point p = new Point(x, y);
                pointsMatrix.Add(p);
                cellCounter += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: You done it, man. Thanks. I just edited it a little, but solution it was you.